# Python 3: convert a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I am looking for a simple method to convert a list into a dictionary. I have a simple list:

```
leet =['a','4','b','l3','c','(','d','[)','e','3','g','6','l','1','o','0','s','5','t','7','w','\/\/']
```

which I want to easily convert to a dictionary. I have tried using defaultdict but I don't quite understand what it is doing ( I found this code in a previous answer):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in leet:
    key ="/".join(item[:-1])
    dic[key].append(item[-1])


>>> dic
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'\\:/:\\': [], '': ['a', '4', 'b', 'c', '(', 'd', 'e',    '3', 'g', '6', 'l', '1', 'o', '0', 's', '5', 't', '7', 'w'], 'l': ['3'], '[': [')'], '\\///\\': ['/']})
```

Ultimately, I want to read in the data from a txt file ( line by line) into a list and convert to a dictionary for the rest of the simple program.
I'm looking for a straight-forward way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'convert into a dictionary' - what do you mean? What will become the keys, what will become the values? Is the list `[key, value, key, value, ...]` or some other strucutre? Do you want to count the items?

Comment: maybe give a real simple example of input and expected output so we know what you want...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clearer. I am just looking to transfer directly[key:value,key:value,..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you're going down the right path with a `defaultdict`, convert to a dict by grouping into pairs, then use `dict.get` to cater for when there isn't a matching key:

```
leet =['a','4','b','l3','c','(','d','[)','e','3','g','6','l','1','o','0','s','5','t','7','w','\/\/']

lookup = dict(zip(*[iter(leet)] * 2))
text = 'how are you?'
blah = ''.join(lookup.get(ch, ch) for ch in text)
# h0\/\/ 4r3 y0u?
```

Comment: Thanks- this does exactly what I want to do. Just a slight problem- your code above returns '\/\/' for 'w' but mine gives me'\\/\\/'- any ideas?

Comment: @user2127168 it doesn't - use `print blah` and you'll see that the extra black-slash is purely for representational purposes and isn't actually in your string... Might be an idea to make that `r'\/\/` to make it more obvious that the backslash isn't for an escape char

Answer (score -1):

```
components_dict = dict(((lambda y: y['id'])(y), y) for y in components)
```

component object as follows:

```
{"id":1234, "name":"xxx"}
```